# How to update PHP version in homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am having a trouble on updating php version in homestead. When I check the version in `homestead ssh` it says it's php version is `PHP 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)`. Now I would like to update the PHP version to 7 for code compatibility. Is there an easy way how to fix this?

I also tried this one from [here](https://laravel-news.com/2015/10/homestead-now-with-php-7-support/)
but got no luck. Thanks

Comment: why dont you update your entire homestead instead of just php? just run vagrant box update on your homestead folder

Comment: @RoccoMilluzzo, yes I did that too and it says `homestead-7: Box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.3.3) is running the latest version.`

Comment: The latest `homestead` version has PHP 7 by default.

Comment: Can you check what happen, when you log into homestead and execute: `apt update` and then `apt upgrade -V`?

Comment: @MinaAbadir, Yes but when I checked my homestead php version it's version  5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have probably Laravel version 5.0 - https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead, in this version Homestead has Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 5.6. To update only PHP to 7.0, you need log into the Homestead, and execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0-mysql php7.0-fpm php7.0-mbstring php7.0-xml php7.0-curl
```

Then you need change `fastcgi_pass` in you configuration files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/*` to this `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`

and at the end restart services:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
/etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this one above but I'm stuck in fastcgi_pass. Where is that located? I'm currently in `vagrant@homestead:~$`

Comment: Now i'm in `etc/nginx/sites-available/` I didn't see any config file here. It's only the list of my sites.

Comment: I get it now, but editing the file throws ` E212: Can't open file for writing`

Comment: If you get the `E212: Can't open file for writing` error, this may be because you need to open the file using `sudo vim <filename>`

Answer (score 14):

Upgrade the laravel/homestead box itself

```
$ vagrant box update
```

ssh into the virtual machine

```
$ vagrant ssh
```

and upgrade everything

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: This helped me: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/929#issuecomment-415474971

Comment: This gives the error `The box you're attempting to add already exists. Remove it before
adding it again or add it with the --force flag.`

Comment: This worked for Laravel Homestead which had its php@7.4. Now I have php@8.0 running.