# PHP 8 running but composer dependencies require >=7 . My machine already has PHP 8.0.3

Tags: php, composer-php, vagrant, homestead

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlRu5.png) Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0". You are running 7.1.33-25+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.

Comment: So upgrade PHP....

Comment: *You are running 7.1.33*

Comment: You are probably running a different version of PHP in the CLI than in the web server

Answer (score 1):

I see you are working with Ubuntu 20.04 or Mint 20.04,

You need to upgrade the current version of PHP, depends on how you install all the packages (LAMP or separatedly)

Open `Terminal` and use this commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install php7.3 php7.3-common php7.3-cli
```

And after that, the dependencies

```
sudo apt install php7.3-bcmath php7.3-bz2 php7.3-curl php7.3-gd php7.3-intl php7.3-json php7.3-mbstring php7.3-readline php7.3-xml php7.3-zip
```

If you work with Apache, you need to install this too.

```
apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3
```

That should fix your problem, don't forget to restart your apache2 server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: when I run the php version function  file it shows that I have PHP 8.0.3 on my system .I'm trying to run a laravel project in Homestead using vagrant , that is were the error is coming from

Comment: See this answer in a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52845975/6342373